# Colorbox doesn't show up - Error $.data(this, colorbox) is undefined

Tags: colorbox, opencart

I am trying to load the pop image on the category page but I get this error upon clicking on the image.

```
Timestamp: 10/27/2012 7:15:10 PM
Error: TypeError: $.data(this, colorbox) is undefined
Source File: http://woodanta.6point9.in/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js
Line: 246
```

The colorbox is working on the products page but not on the category. Can anyone help me with this?

Category: http://woodanta.6point9.in/index.php?route=product/category&path=60

Product: http://woodanta.6point9.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50

Answer (score 3):

Colorbox adds it's settings object to the elements it's assigned to, using jQuery.data(). This settings object is being removed from your elements between the time you assign colorbox, and the time you click on a link.  This usually happens when copy/replacing elements in the document (using $.html()), which does not copy data stored using $.data, rather than cloning them or appending/prepending the existing elements.

I suggest disabling your scripts that are unrelated to colorbox to determine what script is causing the problems.  Also, you may be able to avoid the issue by waiting until the other scripts have executed before assigning colorbox to your elements.